# Automatic Reference Counting: Error with fast enumeration

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

While updating the code below to use Automatic Reference Counting for iOS 5, an error is occurring when the "state->itemPtr" is assigned the buffer when trying to perform Fast Enumeration so that the implementing class can be iterated with the "foreach" loop.  The error I am getting is "Assigning '__autoreleasing id *' to '__unsafe_unretained id*' changes retain/release properties of pointer".  See the line of code with the comment.

```
/*
 * @see http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/05/implementing-countbyenumeratingwithstat.html
 * @see http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-04-16-implementing-fast-enumeration.html
 */
- (NSUInteger) countByEnumeratingWithState: (NSFastEnumerationState *)state objects: (id *)buffer count: (NSUInteger)bufferSize {
    NSUInteger arrayIndex = (NSUInteger)state->state;
    NSUInteger arraySize = [_tuples count];
    NSUInteger bufferIndex = 0;

    while ((arrayIndex < arraySize) && (bufferIndex < bufferSize)) {
        buffer[bufferIndex] = [_tuples objectAtIndex: arrayIndex];
        arrayIndex++;
        bufferIndex++;
    }

    state->state = (unsigned long)arrayIndex;
    state->itemsPtr = buffer; // Assigning '__autoreleasing id *' to '__unsafe_unretained id*' changes retain/release properties of pointer
    state->mutationsPtr = (unsigned long *)self;

    return bufferIndex;
}
```

The _tuples variable in this example is an instance variable of type NSMutableArray.

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to change buffer into `__unsafe_unretained`:

```
- (NSUInteger) countByEnumeratingWithState: (NSFastEnumerationState *)state
                                   objects: (id __unsafe_unretained *)buffer
                                     count: (NSUInteger)bufferSize
```

[source](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/308862-arc-and-nsfastenumeration.html)

Edit: easy way to get rid of the error in `mutationPtr`:

```
state->mutationsPtr = &state->extra[0];
```

Comment: However after I did the "Convert to Objective-C ARC," Xcode changed "state->mutationsPtr = (unsigned long *)self;" to "state->mutationsPtr = (__bridge unsigned long *)self;".  This is now causing another error saying "Incompatible types casting *const __strong to unsigned long with a __bridge cast"  Got any ideas?

Comment: `state->mutationsPtr` shouldn't be used for storing `self`, it should either point to the extra field (easy way) to be unused or to some sort of internal value in your class that changes when the collection changes (hard way), I will edit the answer to include the easy way.

Comment: Does that actually work? Defining the `objects` parameter differently? That gives a compiler error on my system — it doesn't match the declaration.

Comment: The definition from NSEnumerator.h is `- (NSUInteger)countByEnumeratingWithState:(NSFastEnumerationState *)state objects:(id __unsafe_unretained [])buffer count:(NSUInteger)len;`

Answer (score 1):

Ziminji,

I had the same problem, which is how I came across this question.

I solved it by *keeping* the definition of the `objects` parameter as is (e.g., keeping it as `id *`) and instead doing a double cast utilizing a void pointer.

So, while this generated errors for me:

```
state->itemsPtr = (__unsafe_unretained id *)buffer  // Error
```

This worked beautifully:

```
state->itemsPtr = (__unsafe_unretained id *)(void *)buffer  // No error
```

Disclaimer:  I'm not an ARC expert and I can't guarantee you that this won't cause problems with reference counts. However, it *appears* to work correctly in my testing, and it *definitely* compiles without warnings.

BTW, I came across this two-part blog entry which covers Fast Enumeration in a nice amount of depth:

- [Fast Enumeration, Part 1](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/1003-fast-enumeration-part-1/)
- [Fast Enumeration, Part 2](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/1044-fast-enumeration-part-2/)

and also this blog entry on `__unsafe_unretained`:

- [Unsafe at Any Speed](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/939-unsafe-at-any-speed/)