# NSFastEnumeration crashing on C array with ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm initializing a C array of objects and setting the first element:

```
id __strong *_objs =  (id __strong *)calloc(16,sizeof(*_objs));
_objs[0] = @1;
_count++;
```

Then I'm using the following implementation of NSFastEnumeration:

```
- (NSUInteger) countByEnumeratingWithState: (NSFastEnumerationState*)state
                                   objects: (id __unsafe_unretained*)stackbuf
                                     count: (NSUInteger)len
{
    NSUInteger size = _count;
    NSInteger count;
    state->mutationsPtr = (unsigned long *)size;
    count = MIN(len, size - state->state);
    if (count > 0)
    {
        IMP imp = [self methodForSelector: @selector(objectAtIndex:)];
        int p = state->state;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++, p++) {
            stackbuf[i] = (*imp)(self, @selector(objectAtIndex:), p);
        }
        state->state += count;
    }
    else
    {
        count = 0;
    }
    state->itemsPtr = stackbuf;
    return count;
}
```

Unfortunately it crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I run it:

```
for (id object in array){  // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    NSLog(@"%@",object)
}
```

Any idea why?

If you have [CodeRunner](http://krillapps.com/coderunner/), [here](https://gist.github.com/3996072) is an executable version.

Comment: The question being answered, I'll just make a quick unrelated consideration: you're allocating 16 times as much memory as you need with `calloc` — it internally multiplies the number of items by the size of each item, you don't need to do that.

Comment: Yes, thank you, it should be `calloc(16,sizeof(*_objs))`. I edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `mutationsPtr` which points to the memory address 1 which you are not allowed to access (and which is not 4 byte aligned as well):

```
state->mutationsPtr = (unsigned long *)size;
```

Replace it with a valid pointer for starters (careful: the one below may make no sense at all in your scenario, but at least it fixes the EXC_BAD_ACCESS):

```
state->mutationsPtr = (unsigned long *)&_count;
```

Answer (score 1):

@Jano
In case you want to get rid of the compiler warning you will get with recent versions of Xcode (4.6) for

```
   - (NSUInteger) countByEnumeratingWithState: (NSFastEnumerationState*)state
                               objects: (id __unsafe_unretained*)stackbuf
                                 count: (NSUInteger)len
```

because it does not match the original prototype for objects:..stackbuf

```
    - (NSUInteger) countByEnumeratingWithState: (NSFastEnumerationState*)state
                               objects: (__autoreleasing id *)stackbuf
                                 count: (NSUInteger)len
```

see Todd Lehmans answer in [Automatic Reference Counting: Error with fast enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815326/automatic-reference-counting-error-with-fast-enumeration/)